# IMEI mismatch error on restoring nandroid backup from another device(same model)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, backup, clockworkmod-recovery, nandroid, imei

I use a Micromax A52 ...

I have Gingerbread Custom Rom on it...

what i want to do is backup my rom and restore it on another Micromax A52...

so the models are same...vesrsions are same too...

but when restored on the other device, i get an IMEI mismatch error and the Sim Card does not register...

How do i solve this problem?

Using CWM6 ported for my device.

Thankyou! :)